# BST - Deleting a Node

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

so I'm trying to solve a problem from [log2base2.com](http://log2base2.com) involving deleting a node from BST. It works except when trying to delete a node with two children. I know I could simply replace the numbers and then delete the duplicate at the end, but what if my struct has more data than just `key`? So what am I doing wrong please?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

int getRightMin(struct node *root)
{
    //Write your code here
    struct node *temp = root;
    
    while(temp->left!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->left;
    }
    
    return temp;
    
}

struct node *removeNode(struct node *root, int key)
{   
    //Write your code here
    if(root == NULL){return NULL;}
    if(key<root->key){root->left = removeNode(root->left, key);}
    else if(key>root->key){root->right = removeNode(root->right,key);}
    else
    {
        if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
        {
            free(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        else if(root->left)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if(root->right)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *temp = getRightMin(root->right);
            temp->left = root->left;
            temp->right = root->right;
            root = temp;
            root->right = removeNode(root->right, temp->key);
        }
    }
    
    return root;
}

//Don't change the below code
struct node *getNewNode(int val)
{
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->key   = val;
    newNode->left  = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

struct node *insert(struct node *root, int val)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return getNewNode(val);
    if(root->key < val)
        root->right = insert(root->right,val);
    else if(root->key > val)
        root->left = insert(root->left,val);

    return root;
}

void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(root->left);
    printf("%d ",root->key);
    inorder(root->right);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = NULL;
    root = insert(root,100);
    root = insert(root,50);
    root = insert(root,200);
    root = insert(root,150);
    root = insert(root,300);

    int key;
    scanf("%d",&key);

    root = removeNode(root,key);
    inorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

TEST CASE 1:

INPUT: `200`
EXPECTED OUTPUT: `50 100 150 300`
ACTUAL OUTPUT: `50 100 150`

TEST CASE 2:

INPUT: `100`
EXPECTED OUTPUT: `50 150 200 300`
ACTUAL OUTPUT: `50`

Comment: Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: @kaylum yup, done.

Comment: move case `root->left && root->right` higher in if/else cascade. Otherwise it will be catched by `if (root->left)` and `root->right` will leak

Answer (score 0):

You have to reorder conditional in `removeNode()` to:

```
        if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
        {
            free(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (root->left && root->right)
        {
            struct node *temp = getRightMin(root->right);
            temp->left = root->left;
            temp->right = root->right;
            root = temp;
            root->right = removeNode(root->right, temp->key);
        }
        else if(root->left)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else // root->right != NULL
        {
            struct node *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
```

It looks that `(root->left && root->right)` case was caught by `(root->left)` and
reference to `root->right` was lost.

Comment: It's not working, when the node has two children it goes in a loop

Comment: Hmm .. problem is line 'temp->right = root->right;'. It looks that there was one more error

Comment: yep, it creates a cycle, a leaf node pointing back to another node instead of NULL